# Graph Types; The type hierarchy for graphs (JUNG, JUNG2)

Tags: graph, interface, jung, jung2

i am reading your Paper reagardin JUNG-Library. I have seen on Page 8-9 [Paper about JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/JUNG_journal.pdf)

the graphtype hierarchy. In "Figure 1" is the Superinterface ,,ArchetypeGraph'' ,which have two subinterfaces ,,Graph'' and ,,Hypergraph''    BUT 
 in Javadoc the Superinterface is ,,Hypergraph'  [JAVA-Doc](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Graph.html)

what ist the difference between them??? which one is actually the Superinterface and defining the basicoperation about Graphtheory ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that paper has been obsolete since 2009 (when JUNG 2.0 was released); it's referring to JUNG's type system as of v1.x.

In JUNG 2.x, the type system was simplified considerably, and Hypergraph is the superinterface for all graph types.  The Javadoc is correct.

(In JUNG 3.x, which will hopefully be coming out sometime in the next few months, the type system will be simplified even more.)

Comment: Thank u so much ;)